# mysqli connection error (in root folder works, in subfolder not)

Tags: php, path, mysqli, include

i have a file **my_api.php** with the following content:

```
require_once('./api/api_helper.php');
require_once('./includes/db_config.php');
$db = mysqli_connect($dbinfo['host'], $dbinfo['user'], $dbinfo['pass'], $dbinfo['dbname']);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'MySQLi Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error(); exit;
}
```

When i put it into the root dir everything works fine.
Now i put into a subdir called **api** and changed the content of the file to:

```
require_once('./api_helper.php');
require_once('../includes/db_config.php');
$db = mysqli_connect($dbinfo['host'], $dbinfo['user'], $dbinfo['pass'], $dbinfo['dbname']);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'MySQLi Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error(); exit;
}
```

When then i get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/1045):
>   Access denied for user: 'XXXX@localhost' (Using password: YES) in
>   /homepages/XXXX/api/myapi.php on line 13 MySQLi Error: Access denied
>   for user: 'XXXX@localhost' (Using password: YES)

Can anyone please help me to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: check you hostname, username and password

Comment: should ``../`` not be like this ``./../`` ?

Comment: @Sundar: I have checked it. The values (which are in the db_config.php) are correct. When the my_api.php is in the root-folder of the web, then it works. I got only the error, when it is in the api subfolder.

Comment: @ins0: That doesn't work, too. I hvae just test it.

Comment: yeah if the file is not included you should have a different error because you ``require`` the file...when the file is included correctly i don't see any reason the db connection is fail

Answer (score -1):

Edited answer. The error

> Access denied for user: 'XXXX@localhost' (Using password: YES)

means wrong credentials were supplied for the connect. Check the credentials. Whatever folder issues has nothing to do with this error.

<s>I hate to guess but this is not a real question anyway.</s>

It is possible that there is other db_config.php that is getting included with wrong credentials.

Either way, the op should not act like *user* just helplessly *watching* errors, but *do something*. It is not that hard to dig to the problem roots: to echo `$dbinfo`, to check relative paths with `realpath()`, to compare the returned values with desired ones, to turn **full** error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

The program you write is not a black box you have no idea of. It always have intermediate results. It is your duty to verify if they are correct, in case whole program goes wrong.

Comment: I didn't helplessly watching errors because i tried alot before i have posted here. There is no other db_config.php, i echo the $dbinfo via var_dump().
It is a strange thing, why it is doesn't work as soon it is in a subfolder. That was the reason why i asked here.